# Saving specific partitions of Dask DataFrame to parquet

Tags: python, dask, parquet

I have this extremely large dataframe (around 5,000,000 rows) and I have split it into 20 dask partitions.

When I try to save this I my python kernel crashes.

Is there a way of saving each partition, one at a time. Or splitting it into 20 variables?

Dask version = 2022.01.1

Distributed version = ... (if using)

Parquet engine and version = ...

Comment: Please fill in the blank, and any warning/exception you get before crash.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can select individual partitions of your dataframe by using the `.partitions` attribute. For example, this will yield the first partition (still lazy, unless you call `compute()`).

```
ddf.partitions[0]
```

However, it would be good to know why things are failing. Maybe your partitions are too big, or maybe there are too many. Extra details would help, including your version of dask, since some important defaults changed recently to help with stability.

Comment: Im using Dask Version 2022.01.1
When I try save it to parquet file, the kernel keeps restarting. I split it into 10 partitions. They have 2403 tasks in each

Comment: OK, so you should pass an argument which says not to consolidate the metadata pieces. In the most recent dask this is written `write_metadata_file=False`, not sure if this name changed.

Comment: That did not seem to work, when I try repartition to 100MB. I just get a kernel died and  restarted message